# Jquery validation showing errors for 2 divs instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm busy creating validation for this duplicate-able fields, so for on blur if nothing is filled in the input 'Name' and also 'Surname, then a error message will show up, the only problem is that the error shows up for both inputs 'Name' and 'Surname' , instead of one.

Keep in Mind that the the bottom fields are duplicate-able and the validation has to work for them to, hence why the code is written as it is.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/6QTyd/1/)

And the Javascript:

```
 //Error Messages
var messages = {
    "main_name general": "no main name",
};
var g_counter = 1;
var dependant = ["dependant"];
var group;
var name_input_groups = ["name-group-1"];
var surname_input_groups = ["surname-group-1"];
var input_groups = ["group-1"];

var name_fields=[0];
var name_input = "<input class='name' name='name' data-error='Please enter a Dependant name' type='text' />";
var surname_input = "<input id='surname' class='surname' name='surname' type='text' data-error='Surname error' />";

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(name_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(name_input).appendTo('#name-group-1');
    });
    jQuery(name_fields).each(function() {
        jQuery(surname_input).appendTo('#surname-group-1');
    });

    jQuery('#clone').click(function() {
        clone_dependant();
    });

    function clone_dependant() {
        var oldId = g_counter;
        g_counter++;
        currentdep ='dependant-'+g_counter;
        var $clonedDiv = jQuery('#dependant-1').clone(false).attr('id', currentdep);
        var name_newDiv = 'name-group-'+ g_counter;
        var surname_newDiv = 'surname-group-'+ g_counter;
        // Find div's inside the cloned object and set a new id's
        $clonedDiv.find('#name-group-1').attr('id',"name-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#surname-group-1').attr('id',"surname-group-" + g_counter );
        $clonedDiv.find('#dep_num').html(g_counter);
        // Insert the cloned object 
        $clonedDiv.insertAfter("#dependant-" + oldId);
        name_input_groups.push(name_newDiv);
        surname_input_groups.push(surname_newDiv);
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION
//////////////////////////////////////////
$('.name').after('<div class="error"></div>');
$('.surname').after('<div class="error"></div>');
$('.error').hide();

////Validate Surname
$(document).on('blur keyup', 'input.surname', function(e) {
    validate_Surname_Input(this);
});


function validate_Surname(surname_values, el){
    var error_message = $(el).find('input').data('error');
    if (surname_values.length > 0) {
        $(el).find('.error').slideUp('slow');
        return true;
    }else {
        $(el).find('.error').html(error_message).slideDown('slow');
        console.log($(el).find('.error'));
        return false;
    }
};

function validate_Surname_Input(el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    var input_groups = $this.parent();
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(input_groups , function(i){
        var inpg = input_groups[i];
        surname_values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join('');
        isValid = isValid &&
            validate_Surname(surname_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent(), el);
    });
    return isValid;
}
////Validate Surname

////Validate Name
$(document).on('blur keyup', 'input.name', function(e) {
    var values = $(this).val().length;
    validate_Name_Input(this);
});


function validate_Name(name_values, el){
    var error_message = $(el).find('input').data('error');
    if (name_values.length > 0) {
        $(el).find('.error').slideUp('slow');
        return true;
    }else {
        $(el).find('.error').html(error_message).slideDown('slow');
        return false;
    }
};

function validate_Name_Input(el) {
    var $this = $(el);
    var input_groups = $this.parent();
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(input_groups , function(i){
        var inpg = input_groups[i];
        name_values = $.map($(inpg).children('input'), function(e,i){
            return $(e).val();
        }).join('');
        isValid = isValid &&
            validate_Name(name_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent(), el);
    });
    return isValid;
}
////Validate Name

///////////////////////////////////////////
//VALIDATION
/////////////////////////////////////////
var result = {};
var dependants;
var mainmember;
var dep_counter = 0;
function getValues(){
    jQuery('div[class*="mainmember"]').each(function(k, v){
        mainmember = {};
        mainmember['name'] = $(v).find('.name').val();
        mainmember['surname'] = $(v).find('.surname').val();
        result['mainmember'] = mainmember;
    });

    result['dependants'] = [];
    jQuery('div[class*="dependant"]').each(function(k, v){
        dep_counter++
        dependants = {};
        dependants['name'] = $(v).find('.name').val();
        dependants['surname'] = $(v).find('.surname').val();
        result['dependants'].push(dependants);
    });
};

var isValid = true;

jQuery('#submit').click(function(){
var isValid = true;
    $('input.name').each(function(i, el) {
        isValid = isValid &&
            validate_Name_Input(el);
    });
if (isValid) {
    getValues();
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        data: {parameters: jsonData}
    });
    } else {
        console.log('send fail');
    }
});

});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="app_wrap">
<!--Main Member-->
    <div class="title">personal information of principal member:</div>
    <div class="mainmember" id="mainmember" >
    <!--Level 1-->
            <div class="block_wrap left border_right">
                <div class="block">surname:<div class="right"><input class="surname" data-error="Please enter a Surname" /></div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="block_wrap right">
                <div class="block">full name:<div class="right"><input class="name" data-error="Please enter a Main member Name" /></div></div>
        </div>

    <!--Level 1-->
    </div>
<!--Main Member-->

<!--Dependant-->
    <div class="dependant-1" id="dependant-1">
    <div class="title">dependant <span id="dep_num">1</span>:</div>
    <div id="dependant">
    <div class="block_wrap left border_right">
            <div class="block">surname:<div id="surname-group-1" class="right"></div></div>
    </div>
    <!--Level 1-->
    <div class="block_wrap right">
            <div class="block">full name:<div id="name-group-1" class="right"></div></div>
    </div>
    <!--Level 1-->
   </div>
   </div>  
<!--Dependant-->
   <button id="clone">Add a Dependant</button>
   <button id="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess there is a issue of reference to the input. I am looking into it.Just hang on :)

Comment: I am very uncertain what it is you are trying to do. Your JS feels rather huge for what it is you are trying to achieve, especially considering you're using jQuery. Can you provide more insight on what expected output is? Judging by your explanation of the problem, I feel `validate_Name(name_values, input_groups.parent().parent().parent(), el);` is what's wrong, you need 2 parents up, not 3.

Comment: @Khez I too think the same the JS and the other stuffs could have been a bit less for the things that Dawin is trying to achieve... :(

Comment: well see this is a small part of the end thing, and I'm not super experienced in jQuery so alot of questions have been asked on stack overflow, Heres the entire project : http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/7ycUT/ im just busy with validation

Comment: And here's a valid ID aswell: 85 0929 5266086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/6QTyd/5/

Also note the changes in these areas :

```
validate_Surname(surname_values, input_groups.parent().parent());
```

and

```
validate_Name(name_values, input_groups.parent().parent());
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be validating the dependants surname

Comment: Yes , it does... Can you tell what is the problem now..?

Comment: I think i fixed it, sorry not your fault: i just replaced the on click with var isValid = true;
    $('input.name, input.surname').each(function(i, el) {
        isValid = isValid &&
   validate_Surname_Input(el);
    });